# Tengo un Error en mi sql "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysqldb

después de haber hecho mi código php para enviar este dato a mi base de datos me sale el siguiente error

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in
```

e investigado en varios foros pero ninguno  me ha funcionado porfavor ayudeme aca les dejo mi codigo php

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = 'Localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_NAME = 'mudanzas';
$DB_PASSWORD = "";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME);
$nombre_user_cot =$_POST['name'];
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
  $db_itio = "INSERT INTO datos('nombre') VALUES('$nombre_user_cot')";
  $insert = mysqli_query('$conexion' , '$db_itiodb_itio');
  if(!$insert){
    echo"<br><p class='bad'>Error SQL</p>";
  }
}

?>
```

y mi codigo html esta bien no tiene errores

Comment: El primer parametro de mysqli_query debe ser una conexión, no una cadena. Has puesto entre comillas simples la conexión y te está interpretando un literal `$conexion`. Quita esas comillas

Comment: Gracias pero aun tengo Error en mi sql

Comment: Pues como en muchos sitios y en muchas preguntas de SO, te invito a añadir un die después de tu query, mostrando el resultado de mysqli_error, así podrás ver el último error de SQL. O mejor aún, añadir la ejecución de la consulta dentro de un try/catch y evalúa el mensaje de exception

Comment: esperame lo añado

Comment: es un or die o solo un die

Comment: que va despues del or die

Comment: El que quieras. La cosa es que consigas más información para resolver tu problema. El segundo problema parece también el segundo parsmetro, que también tiene comillas y te está evaluando la $db_itiodb_itio como literal. Además esa no es la variable de la sql,  sino $db_itio

Comment: `Or die echo mysqli_error(); ` . Pero como te digo revisa los dos parámetros de `mysqli_query`

Comment: `$insert = mysqli_query('$conexion' , '$db_itiodb_itio');`, debe ser solo `$conexion`, sin comillas

Comment: miren otro Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\registrar.php on line 27 la linea 27 es la de`` $insert = mysqli_query($conexion ,'$db_itio') Or die echo mysqli_error();``

Comment: la linea 27 es la de $insert = mysqli_query($conexion ,'$db_itio') Or die echo mysqli_error(); @Jakala

Comment: En tu insert into`$db_itio = "INSERT INTO datos('nombre') Debe ser sin comillas: ``datos(nombre)`` lo mismo en el insert: ``$insert = mysqli_query('$conexion' , '$db_itiodb_itio');`` debe ser sin comillas: ``$insert = mysqli_query($conexion ,...``

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias como les podria ayudar @all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la linea

```
$insert = mysqli_query('$conexion' , '$db_itiodb_itio');
```

deberias quitar las comillas de $conexion, dado que esta mysqli_query, espera como primer parametro la conexion y alli estas pasando como string